# Placing TextView on different positions on the screen

Tags: android, canvas, textview, paint

I got a list of images, and when a person clicks on an item it goes to an activity and set an ImageView with that image.

What I want to do is: on each image set a position to the TextView. If the person selects image A, the TextView is on postion X. If B, on position Y... And I would like to paint on the text on that position.

I know how to paint the text on the image and save it on the SD Card, but I don't know how to set a position for the textview on each image and how to get that position and use it on the image.

Is it possible? Too complicated? I have about 10 images with 4 textviews each.

I think that I can do this with AbsoluteLayout, but it's deprecated. Or I could use lots of TextViews and set them Visible/Gone, but would be a lot of TextViews (Is it easier?).

Two more questions: 1) I have a custom style for my TextView, is it possible to use it when painting it and saving the image?

2) How do I break a line on it? When my text is to big it just keep going off the screen, how do I limit it and break it into a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to change the images with others in different positions so I'm using 2 TextViews in the same place for 9 images and 1 other TextView (set "Invisible" for the first 9 images) to complete the 10th image.

That will work for now.

Sorry for the thread guys.